# Dissolve polygons in Single-parts and calculating statistics for those single-part polygons only

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, dissolve

I have a polygon shapefile. Which have some numeric attributes (`A`, `B`). I clustered the shapefile in five groups (`labels`) based on an attribute(`A`) and want to dissolve them while aggregating other attributes (`A`, `B`).
Code for that is:

```
import geopandas as gpd
# suppose clustered_df is a gdf obtained after clustering
db_clustered_dissolve = clustered_df .dissolve(by='labels'
            , aggfunc= {'labels':'count','A': 'sum', 'B': 'sum'})
```

The above code dissolves the dataframe by `labels` column and create Multi-part polygons.

I know that if I want only single-part polygons then I can use `explode()` on the dataframe `db_clustered_dissolve` but I can not accuratly calculate `A`, `B` and `count` for those resulted single part dissolved polygons because every single-part polygon will have same values for `A`, `B` and `count` as their corresponding Multi-part polygons.

I'm having this idea that I can use something that only single-part polygon would be created while dissolving and statistics for those could be calculated on the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dissolve by `labels` and contiguity to get what you want. Therefore, you first need to identify contiguous components and then do the dissolve. That is a simple operation with `libpysal`.

Using the example data from geopandas:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import libpysal

earth = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
earth = earth.explode()  # to get single part input

# create spatial weights matrix
W = libpysal.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(earth)

# asssing component labels
earth['comp'] = W.component_labels

dissolved = earth.dissolve(['continent', 'comp'])
```

See libpysal documentation for more on spatial weights matrices: https://pysal.org/libpysal/